# CakePHP - optimizing specific urls by stripping down unnecessary functionality

Tags: php, cakephp

Besides the obvious like caching pages, using recursive and containable, what is a good way to really minimize the memory footprint on certain urls, without just going out and writing flat php?

For example, I have certain controller actions (and model methods) that have minimal interaction with the rest of the system but are accessed frequently by many users at the same time.

Or another example would be an API endpoint. It only pulls some specific data, but uses way more memory than it should.

Any way to optimize these actions but still staying within CakePHP? (maybe by selectively disabling some heavy CakePHP stuff for them)

I'm currently on CakePHP 1.3.x, but moving to 2.x is on my todo list.

Comment: This isn’t really a specific question so voting to close. But I’d suggest profiling your application to see what *exactly* is using resources, and then reacting to those findings, i.e. caching common queries etc.

Comment: @MartinBean Fair enough, if it gets closed I'll know I have to approach this differently. I am already caching queries and optimizing my database (using indexes, checking the slow query log etc) and I've narrowed it down. burzum has also pointed to profiling the request so I'll update my answer soon. I was asking with the idea that I might be missing some obvious/standard solution to this type of problem.

Comment: It’s hard to say, as it could literally be anything. We’ve not seen any application, we don’t know what server your app’s running on or how your server’s configured. There’s just too many possibilities. As @burzum and I say, profile—that’ll point you in the right direction.

Comment: If you still use Apache replace it with Nginx. Are you using APC? If not use it. There is a ton of possible optimizations setting wise as well but it all depends on knowing the environment and code. The whole code, not just a piece.

Comment: Right, got it. Will have to profile and upgrade (and then profile again). Will look into moving to Nginx as well, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm currently on CakePHP 1.3.x, but moving to 2.3 is on my todo list.

Move to 2.x which will give you a boost of sometime 50% better performance and I think also less memory usage. 2.0 loads models and other things lazy. So if something is not needed it won't be loaded as long as it is not needed. You can get that lazy loading for models for 1.3 as well. See https://github.com/lorenzo/lazy_loader

> It only pulls some specific data, but uses way more memory than it
>   should.

Well, how do you know that? Did you [profile the request](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler)? If yes what was the slowest or most memory eating method call? It is impossible to give any advice besides caching without know and profiling the code.

I would not waste more time with optimizing the old 1.3 app much when you're going to switch to 2.x soon. Why do you want to go for 2.3? There is already 2.4 and 2.5 is coming.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, sounds like upgrading is the best way to go. After that I'll be able to see if there are still issues on these specific requests and profile them if needed. Was just putting this off for too long as the application is very big already and migrating sounds like a pandoras box at the moment. (and yeah, will move to the latest stable 2.x version, will update question). Thanks!

Comment: If your code is well written and following the conventions migrating to Cake 2.x should not take you more than 1 or 2 weeks. We've migrated a ~560 table medical app in that time. Most work can be done by using the upgrade shell and then just fix what it could not do automatically.

Comment: @Nebojsac the time required to migrate an app varies from app to app - it could (OR should) take only a few hours. I'd guestimate a day's work per 10 controllers as a generous budget. It's definitely in your interest to upgrade and review rather than try and optimize the existing code and then upgrade.

Comment: Thanks both of you. It makes sense to upgrade, and the sooner the better. Will tackle that problem first then.